# Is a swap fixed rate always a par yield?

Tags: swaps, forward, libor, ois

I am learning about using the OIS fixed rate to value a plain vanilla LIBOR swap. I'm using *Bond Math* by Smith, and the accompanying online addendum.

To bootstrap the discount factors, the author treats the OIS fixed rate as a par yield. If $d_i$ are the OIS discount factors, $R_N$ is the OIS fixed rate, $m$ is the periodicity, then this means that for any maturity $N$ we have

(!) $\frac{R_N}{m}\sum_{i=1}^Nd_i + d_N = 1$.

My questions are:

**1) Why should the OIS fixed rate be a par yield?**

**2) General question: Is the fixed rate of an arbitrary fixed/floating swap always a par yield in the above sense?**

Here is what I suspect, based on my (limited) experience with plain vanilla LIBOR swaps. If $f_i$ are the relevant "implied" forward rates, we want

$(1+f_i/m) = \frac{d_{i-1}}{d_i}$ for all $i$.

It seems that this condition is equivalent to the requirement that

$\sum_{i=1}^Nf_id_i + d_N = 1$

and hence to equation $(!)$ above by the definition of $R_N$. In other words, equation $(!)$ is a way of enforcing the compatibility of the $f_i$ and the $d_i$ without explicitly referring to the $f_i$.

**3. Is the above speculation correct, or at least on the right track?**

Comment: When you invest in the overnight market you put in 100, you receive interest and you get your 100 back at the end. So in that sense it is like a par bond.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you have a hint of how this could work for other types of floating rates? Or perhaps a source where this point is treated in more generality, or maybe just in more detail?